# How to call a function with this parameter: fun(Ty param[NUM])?

Tags: c++, arrays, function-declaration

In an API header file I found a strange function declaration:

```
void API_GetParameter(API_SOMESTRUCT param[API_NUM_CONST]);
```

where `API_NUM_CONST` is an enum value and `API_SOMESTRUCT` is a struct, so my guess is that `param` is an array of that struct.

The function thus expects an existing data field which it fills or changes. *I cannot say what the API function does internally.*

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
API_SOMESTRUCT *param = new API_SOMESTRUCT[API_NUM_CONST];
API_GetParameter(param);
// ... read out param
delete[] param;
param = NULL;
```

But I suspect this piece of code to be responsible for a heap corruption error I'm recently getting and I'm not sure if my call is correct.

---

I understand function headers with non-const arrays for parameters that look like this:

```
void fun(int *arr); // expects a pointer to a non-const int array of arbitrary size...
```

- So what is the exact meaning of the API function declaration?
- Is `param` being called by value or by reference?
- And how do I correctly call that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration `void f(int x[3]);` is the same as `void f(int *x);`  So, the function needs to receive a valid pointer to `API_SOMESTRUCT`. Otherwise, you can't know what it is going to do, how many elements it expects, or what it is going to do with them. You have to read the documentation.

If I had to guess, I would have passed in an array of `API_NUM_CONST` elements, just allocated on the stack:

```
API_SOMESTRUCT param[API_NUM_CONST]
API_GetParameter(param);
// use param
```

Comment: 'Declaration void f(int x[3]); is the same as void f(int *x);' -> Doesn't the first declaration specify the size of the array then? Or is that just a hint?

Comment: Depending on the size of the struct and the number of elements, it might be more appropriate to declare a `std::vector<API_SOMESTRUCT> v(API_NUM_CONST);` and pass a `&v[0]`.

Comment: @Martin In a function declaration like `int i[3]`, the `3` is pure comment; this is converted by the compiler to `int* i`, and `int i[3]` and `int i[100]` are the same type.

Comment: Martin: just a hint, and that only to the user, not the compiler. To the compiler, it's 100% equivalent to int*.

Comment: @JamesKanze, SebastianRedl Great, that's the information I was searching for. Just didn't know how to ask...

Comment: @Martin, changing the allocation from heap to stack won't remove the problem in the API (if there is any). Usually if I suspect that a piece of code is creating trouble, I just comment out the  piece of code and try again to see if the trouble is still there.